# C - getting prime numbers from particular BIG RANGE

Tags: c, arrays, memory

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define UPPER_LIMIT 2147483647
void sieve(unsigned long int n, unsigned long int primes[]);  
main()  
{  
    unsigned long int low, up, steps;  
    unsigned long int v[UPPER_LIMIT];  
    sieve(UPPER_LIMIT, v);  
    scanf("%ld\n",&steps);  
    for (unsigned long int i=0;i<steps;i++){  
        scanf("%ld %ld\n",&low,&up);  
        for(unsigned long int j=low; j<up; j++){  
            if (v[j] == 1){  
                printf("%ld\n",j);  
            }  
        }   
    }  
}  
void sieve(unsigned long int n, unsigned long int primes[])  
{  
    for (unsigned long int i=0;i<n;i++){  
        primes[i]=1;  
    }  
    primes[0]=0,primes[1]=0;   

    for (unsigned long int i=2;i<sqrt(n);i++) {  
        for (unsigned long int j=i*i;j<n;j+=i){  
            primes[j] = 0;  
        }  
    }  
}
```

I'm trying to solve the problem of printing prime numbers from a particular range. 
At first `scanf` we get number of cases to be reviewed. The range is given by next lines of stdin e.g (1 10) upper value can be at max 2147483647. I'm using Sieve of Erastostenes to find prime numbers. After that I would like to `printf` prime numbers in ascending order. Unfortunately I'm getting a Runtime Error, and I assume that is because of the very big array I'm trying to create. I need advice on the possible solution of the problem.

Example of stdin:

```
1  
1 10
```

Example of stdout:

```
2  
3  
7
```

Comment: `unsigned long int v[UPPER_LIMIT];` is probably too big. Try creating with `malloc`.

Comment: Since when was 5 not a prime number between 1 and 10?

Answer (score 1):

There is no point in using an `unsigned long` array to store only `0` or `1`.

You only need `2147483647 / 8` bits to store all the information you need, so you should declare an array of at most `2147483647 / 8 + 1` bytes:

```
const unsigned int SIZE = 1 + (2147483647 / 8);
unsigned char primes[SIZE];
```

Or even better, through heap allocation:

```
const unsigned int SIZE = 1 + (2147483647 / 8);
unsigned char *primes = (unsigned char*)malloc(SIZE);
```

The array initialization becomes:

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < SIZE ; i++ ){  
    primes[i] = 1;
}
```

The access to individual bits of the array can be done with the bitwise operators `>>`, `<<`, and `&`. Implementing this is left as an exercise, since this looks like an university exercise.

Comment: If you're using C++, you can use the specialized `std::vector<bool>` for an easy to use implementation where each index is stored as an individual bit.

Answer (score 0):

Globally declare the primes array with max size.
You can use vector to store primes (c++ container).
And array size can be 10^7 to 10^8 at best,
you can not declare `unsigned long int v[2147483647];` this big array
Also you can't solve the problem through this approach :) .

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to create a local variable, which in most implementations lives on the stack, of a very large size.  With 2G elements of type `unsigned long`, you're most likely looking at either 8 GB or 16 GB.  That's way too large for the stack.

Create this variable as a global instead.  That way it will not live on the stack but in (depending on the implementation) the data section.

Also, since this array is only being assigned the values 0 and 1, change the type of the array to `char` so each element only uses 1 byte.  That will save you a lot of memory.